# Ruby - Net::HTTP gives no multipart boundary was found error with multipart/form-data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multipartform-data, net-http

I am trying to consume an **multipart/form-data** API with *Ruby - Net::HTTP* but it gives below error

```
{"error":{"code":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR","message":"Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: 
the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found","data":{}}}
```

cURL is working but Ruby - Net::HTTP request is not working, below is the request -

```
require "uri"
require "net/http"

url = URI("[base_url]/rest/v1/companies/11/notifications/email-with-attachment?content_type=static")

https = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
https.use_ssl = true

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
request["client"] = "mobi"
form_data = [
  ['email_data', '{"message":"Test\\tMessage","type":"mobi","priority":"LOW","email":{"to_email_ids":["awadesh@temp.com"],"cc_email_ids":[],"bcc_email_ids":[],"from_email_id":"automation@temp.com","subject":"subject - test email","attachment":[]}}'],
  ['attachment', File.open('/Users/dummy/Desktop/Screenshot 2022-11-07 at 10.45.11 AM.png')]
]
request.set_form form_data, 'multipart/form-data'
response = https.request(request)
puts response.read_body
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The parts of the body need to be split into parts with diffenent `Content-Disposition` and `Content-Type` headers as you're sending both binary and normal form data. `Net::HTTP` doesn't actually provide a method for this - its a very low level and clunky library. Use the [multipart-post](https://github.com/socketry/multipart-post) gem or one of the [many other more complete HTTP libs like HTTParty or Faraday](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients).

Comment: What you're doing here is just sending a single part filled with junk data - which is why the server is complaining that there is no boundry. cURL works since its automatically splitting the body into parts  for you. https://everything.curl.dev/http/multipart